# System.InvalidOperationException: The current runtime target framework is not compatible with 'project'

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I started a new ASP.NET project using 1.0.0. I can build and run the project fine, but when I try to run entity framework commands (I've been testing with "dnx ef") in the developer command prompt, I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The current runtime target framework is not compatible with 'myprojectname'
```

I haven't found a solution to this anywhere else on stack overflow. Most of the questions seem geared toward solving when the project fails to build or run, and that is not a problem. Here are the relevant parts of my project.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": { }
  },
```

And my global.json:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003121"
  }
}
```

And here is the full output when I run "dnx ef":

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The current runtime target framework is not compatible with 'myprojectname'.
Current runtime target framework: 'DNX,Version=v4.5.1 (dnx451)'
 Version:      1.0.0-rc1-16609
 Type:         Clr
 Architecture: x86
 OS Name:      Windows
 OS Version:   10.0
 Runtime Id:   win10-x86

Please make sure the runtime matches a framework specified in project.json
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.DefaultHost.GetEntryPoint(String applicationName)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.ExecuteMain(DefaultHost host, String applicationName, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync(List`1 args, IRuntimeEnvironment env, String appBase, FrameworkName targetFramework)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.ExecuteAsync(String[] args, BootstrapperContext bootstrapperContext)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.Execute(String[] args, BootstrapperContext bootstrapperContext)
```

What do I need to do to get EF to run migrations? This has been driving me bonkers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dnx and commands went away post RC1 you should use `dotnet ef`

Comment: Ahh, thank you! I've been out of the ASP.NET 5 loop for a few beta releases.